# Querying same column from two different tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join

I would like to get every `patch_no` that specyfic `champion` is at like e.g. 'Katarina' and then I would like to sort those `Patches` with `Created` column which is in different table, `Patch_No` are connected between tables.

```
SELECT Patch_No 
  FROM champions , info 
 WHERE Champion = 'Katarina'
 ORDER BY Created DESC
```

Sample `info` table:

```
ID  Patch_No  Created  
165 1.0.0.126 2015-08-22 21:20:03
164 1.0.0.125 2015-08-22 21:03:40
163 1.0.0.124 2015-08-22 19:28:12
162 1.0.0.123 2015-08-22 19:03:59
161 1.0.0.122 2015-08-22 18:12:19
160 1.0.0.121 2015-08-22 17:30:26
159 1.0.0.120 2015-08-21 23:19:16
158 1.0.0.119 2015-08-21 22:13:31
157 1.0.0.118 2015-08-21 21:53:44
```

And Sample `champions` table :

```
ID Patch_No Champion
66 1.0.0.32 Ashe
67 1.0.0.32 Cho’Gath
68 1.0.0.32 1-leimerdinger
69 1.0.0.32 Karthus
70 1.0.0.32 Katarina
71 1.0.0.32 Nunu
```

Comment: Use a `JOIN` to get related rows between the tables. This is SQL 101.

Comment: Katarina only has one patch_no

Comment: @ Strawberry:- thats may be because of sample data, in actual data, may be OP have more

Comment: Too large? By adding a single extra row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing good, just use [INNER Join](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) To get desired result. You can use ASC or DESC in Order by clause based on how you want to soreted out data.

```
SELECT C.Patch_No 
  FROM champions C
     INNER JOIN info I ON C.Patch_No  = I.Patch_No 
 WHERE Champion = 'Katarina'
 ORDER BY Created DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this query too :

```
SELECT C.Patch_No 
FROM champions C, info I 
WHERE  C.Patch_No  = I.Patch_No 
AND Champion = 'Katarina'
ORDER BY Created DESC
```

;-)